# Transform UNIQUE constraint into CHECK or trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, constraints, unique

I'd like to modify my table constraints. Since now, name have to be unique. But I'd like to have unique name, only when a row with given name is active. So i added column is_active.

```
CREATE TABLE item
(
(...)
name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
is_active boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
CONSTRAINT uc_item_name UNIQUE (name),
(...)
)
```

Can I delete unique constraint and add trigger, or function call which would do so:

- if given new name does not exists in table return true or allow
  insert,
- if given new name exits in at least one row, iterate over
  them and check if at least one is active. if yes - fail insert
  otherwise add row to table.

Can anyone help me? It is just beginning of my adventure with Postgres. I'm using version 9.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a partial unique index:

```
create unique index on item (name) 
where is_active;
```

Comment: that's the anwser! thank you. I am just wondering if i'm able to do this by CHECK constraint which calls a function that returns a boolean. is it possible? I ask, because I tought it would be the most elegant way to achive my goal

Comment: @Konrad: Not possible at the default [isolation level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html); two simultaneous inserts using the same `name` can't see each other, and both would pass the check. A unique index handles concurrency automatically.